# UPDATE sentence to Function PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have the following code which works:

```
UPDATE backup_factura 
    SET tipo = CASE 
                 WHEN total_fact <=100 THEN 'X'
                 WHEN total_fact <=200 THEN 'Y'
                 ELSE 'Z'
               END
RETURNING *;
```

My teacher asked me to convert it into a function.
I have tried the following:

```
CREATE Function sp_test_case () returns void as $$ 
BEGIN

  UPDATE backup_factura 
    SET tipo = CASE 
                 WHEN total_fact <=100 THEN 'X'
                 WHEN total_fact <=200 THEN 'Y'
                 ELSE 'Z'
               END
  RETURNING *;

RETURN;   
END;   
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But when I execute the function, I get:

```
********** Error **********
ERROR: query has no destination for result data
SQL state: 42601
Context: PL / pgSQL sp_test_case () function in line 4 SQL statement
```

I have also tried with a more complex approach:

```
CREATE Function sp_test_case () returns void as $$ 
DECLARE
    cont int=(Select MAX(id_fact)from backup_factura);
BEGIN

  while cont>0
  LOOP

    UPDATE backup_factura
    SET tipo= CASE 
            WHEN ((total_fact) <=100) THEN 'X'
            WHEN ((total_fact) <=200) THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'Z'
           END;

    WHERE id_fact=cont;

    cont:=cont-1;

   END LOOP;

RETURN;   
END;   
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I get:

```
********** Error **********
ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 283
```

The point is to show something like this:

[image: Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `return query` syntax and return a `setof` your table:

```
CREATE Function sp_test_case () RETURNS SETOF backup_factura AS $$ 
BEGIN

  RETURN QUERY
  UPDATE backup_factura 
    SET tipo = CASE 
                 WHEN total_fact <=100 THEN 'X'
                 WHEN total_fact <=200 THEN 'Y'
                 ELSE 'Z'
               END
  RETURNING *;
END;   
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I tried your code but it just shows: "(5,48,101.25,2012-05-16,"2012-05-31 00:00:00",Y)" and 3 more equivalent rows. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If you need the columns returned separately, you should call the function with `select * from sp_test_case()`. If that isn't the issue, please explain why this return value is incorrect.

Comment: I already did it. What I cannot understand is how to make the table appear like the one I have just uploaded instead of just one column with the data I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: `select * from sp_test_case()` (as opposed to `select sp_test_case()`) should have done the trick... Which Postgress version are you using? And which client?

Comment: My mistake. I noticed I was missing the *. My fault. Topic solved. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your plpgsql function like @Mureinik posted. Or, better yet, use a simpler [SQL function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html):

```
CREATE FUNCTION sp_test_case ()
   RETURNS SETOF backup_factura AS
$func$
UPDATE backup_factura 
SET    tipo = CASE WHEN total_fact <= 100 THEN 'X'
                   WHEN total_fact <= 200 THEN 'Y'
                   ELSE 'Z' END
RETURNING *;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM sp_test_case();
```

Comment: When I run the Select sp_test_case ();
I get the same as @Mureinik's code: "(5,48,101.25,2012-05-16,"2012-05-31 00:00:00",Y)"

Comment: With the first code I posted I can get the table at the end of my post. But with your code I just get a simple column

Comment: @MichVellve: Consider the call syntax I added. `SELECT * FROM ..` is used to decompose the row into individual columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My mistake. Thanks a lot for your quick answer!